# Php скачать оригинальный файл

Tags: php, yii2

Есть pdf. От него взят хеш в Крипто Про. При скачивании через

```
        \Yii::$app->response->sendFile($path, $title, ['inline' => false])->send();
```

хеш совпадает

при использовании

```
    $file_get_contents = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Согласие.pdf');
    header("Content-type:application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=Согласие.pdf");
    echo $file_get_contents;
```

хеш не совпадает

есть ли способ отдать оригинальный файл как это реализовано в Yii2?

Comment: хэш надо полагать вы таки считаете от контента а не от заголовков. Возможно, каким-то боком участвует имя файла, убедитесь что файл действительно корректный скачивается, а не пустой, например, и сверьте имена

Comment: файл корректный

Comment: попробуйте `application/octet-stream`, чтобы документ как бинарный файл скачивался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $path = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Согласие.pdf';
    $file_get_contents = file_get_contents($path);
    header("Content-type:application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=Согласие.pdf");
    header("Content-Length:" . filesize($path));
    echo $file_get_contents;
```

Content-Length - в данном случае критичен